# Without using ajax Complex object as GET @RequestParam

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, jsp

I have to pass quite a few parameters in an url in a jsp which is sent to a spring mvc controller from the jsp. Some of it can be combined into one object and some cannot. I am using a form to combine some of the parameters so that I don't mess up my controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/action")
public @ResponseBody List<RandomObject> myAction(
    @RequestParam(value = "abc", required = false) int abc,
    @RequestParam(value = "cat", required = false) String cat,
    @RequestParam(value = "dog", required = false) String dog,
    @RequestParam(value = "reindeer", required = false) String reindeer,
    @RequestParam(value = "deer", required = false) int deer) { ... }
```

so except for abc, the others can be converted into an object with cat, dog, reindeer and deer as attributes.

```
public class RandomObject {
    private String cat;
    private String dog;
    private String deer;
    private String reindeer;

    //Getters and setters
    ...
}
```

My question is how do i receive it in the controller? I am NOT using AJAX. I tried in vain  something like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/action")
public @ResponseBody List<RandomObject> myAction(
    @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) int page,
     RandomObject object,) {
```

and

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/action")
    public @ResponseBody List<RandomObject> myAction(
        @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) int page,
         @RequestParam(value = "object", required = false) RandomObject object,) {
```

and

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/action")
        public @ResponseBody List<RandomObject> myAction(
            @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) int page,
             @ModelAttribute(value = "object", required = false) RandomObject object,) {
```

BUt none of it worked. Please note I am not using AJAX.

Comment: You first attempt should work (without the last `,`). What does your request contain?

Comment: chuck the comma please, its just a typo here. I will make an edit. the url gets activated on click of a button..url is something like xyz.htm?page=1&cat=4&deer=2 etc.

Comment: The first solution should work. Something else is going wrong. What are you getting as a response?

Comment: When i try to see what object is, I get something but the individual attributes of RandomObject, i.e, cat, dog, deer are all null when they shouldn't be.